# iOS writing to Firebase leads to crash

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wonder if my code is thread safe, in tableView(_ tableView:, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath:) I create an action that accepts a friend request. The method is invoked from a blok of UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (action, view, handler) in }

The actual Firebase call is like this:

```
class func acceptInvite(uid: String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
    guard let user = currentUser else { completion(false); return }
    usersRef.child(user.uid).child("invites").queryEqual(toValue: uid).ref.removeValue()
    usersRef.child(user.uid).child("friends").childByAutoId().setValue(uid)
    usersRef.child(uid).child("friends").childByAutoId().setValue(user.uid)
    completion(true)
}
```

[image from debug navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HioGC.png)

It would be great if someone had an explanation.

edit: I think the problem is in my async loop to get the userdata

```
class func get(type: String, completion: @escaping ([Friend])->Void) {
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    guard let user = currentUser else { completion([]); return }
    usersRef.child(user.uid).child(type).observe(.value){ (snapshot) in
        guard let invitesKeyValues = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else { completion([]); return }
        var optionalFriendsDictArray: [[String: Any]?] = []
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for (_, inviteUID) in invitesKeyValues {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            usersRef.child(inviteUID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let friend = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                optionalFriendsDictArray.append(friend)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), execute: {
            let friends = optionalFriendsDictArray.flatMap({ (optional) -> Friend? in
                Friend.init(userDictionary: optional)
            })
            completion(friends)
        })
    }
}
```

This problem really gets me thinking about Firebase usage. I could add more information about the user at the friends key of a user so you don't have to query all the user to populate a small list with a name and a photo.
But what about viewing your friends posts on your timeline, your definitely not going to copy every friends' post into the users object. ???

Comment: It has to do with the observer of the user. The observer seems to be the reason for the crash when I want to write to the user that is being observed.

Comment: Can you share details about the crash log

Comment: There is nothing in the log, I think it a threading issue looking at the debug navigator

Comment: There is an image of the debug navigator in the post, maybe that gives some information

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by fetching the data with an observe single event and using the childadded and childremoved observers for mutations.